# If $(\xi_k), k \ge 0$ is a sequence of iid Gaussian variables, does it hold a.s. that $\sum \xi_k^2 = +\infty $?

Tags: probability

I think that the probability is either 0 or 1 by Kolmogorov 0-1 law.

Comment: Use the $ symbol to enclose your expressions in Latex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a straight application of the [converse of the Borel-Cantelli Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Converse_result) looking at $\xi_k > M$ for some fixed $M > 0$.